# Weird Linker Error

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, linker-errors

```
#include path
include_directories(
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
${HGE_INCLUDE_DIR}
${IKL_INCLUDE_DIR}
${BOOST_DIRECTORY}
)

#include all files
FILE(GLOB CORE_SRCS source/core/*.cpp)
FILE(GLOB TOOL_SRCS source/tools/*.cpp)
FILE(GLOB GAME_SRCS source/game/*.cpp)

#Making a compiled library
add_library(GAMECORE_LIBRARY ${CORE_SRCS} ${HGE_LIBRARY} ${HGE_HELPER_LIBRARY})

#add executable
add_executable(DemoGame ${GAME_SRCS})

##link executable to HGE lib
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(DemoGame ${HGE_LIBRARY} ${HGE_HELPER_LIBRARY} ${IKL_LIBRARY} GAMECORE_LIBRARY)

if(BUILD_TOOLS)
add_executable(EntityTool ${TOOL_SRCS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(EntityTool ${HGE_LIBRARY} ${HGE_HELPER_LIBRARY} ${IKL_LIBRARY} GAMECORE_LIBRARY)
endif(BUILD_TOOLS)
```

this is my current cmake ..

I get a weird linker error for hgeGUI class
eg : DemoGame/source/core/GameMainMenu.cpp:74: undefined reference to `hgeGUI::hgeGUI()'

This only happens when I try to compile the core files into a static library.
When I add the executable with the CORE_SRCS and remove the dependencies on my current compiled library .. it will work fine..

Also I tried copy pasting the hgegui.cpp file into my core sources directory .. and change the `#include "..\..\include\hgegui.h"` to `#include "hgegui.h"`

After that my linker code resolves the issue but I get segmentation faults but I m guessing linking the file in the previous step was not right ..

Here's a link to their .h file
http://trac.assembla.com/snowscape/browser/hge/include/hgegui.h

Comment: Please don't add [solved] to your target. If your question is answered, accept the answer that helped best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're misusing the `${HGE_LIBRARY}` and `${HGE_HELPER_LIBRARY}` variables.

In an `add_library` call, you include all the source files which make up that library.

In a `target_link_libraries` call, you specify libraries or flags to use when linking the target.

So, if `${HGE_LIBRARY}` and `${HGE_HELPER_LIBRARY}` specify paths to libraries which you want to specify as dependencies of `GAMECORE_LIBRARY`, you need to do:

```
add_library(GAMECORE_LIBRARY ${CORE_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(GAMECORE_LIBRARY ${HGE_LIBRARY} ${HGE_HELPER_LIBRARY})
```

The dependencies are transitive, so this means when you specify `GAMECORE_LIBRARY` as a dependency of `DemoGame` and `EntityTool`, then CMake recognises that `${HGE_LIBRARY}` and `${HGE_HELPER_LIBRARY}` are also dependencies, so you can remove them from the `target_link_libraries` calls for `DemoGame` and `EntityTool` if you want.

For further info on `add_library` and `target_link_libraries`, run:

```
cmake --help-command add_library
cmake --help-command target_link_libraries
```

Comment: Ok That worked .. I didn't know that target_link_library would work for libraries. Thanks